# Create fixed div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created a div with height and width in '%' and also i want to make it responsive.

```
<div id="imgContainer" style="background-color: #FFD993;
            color: darkbrown;
            border: 1px outset #A61C14;
            -moz-border-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 8px; width:100%;text-align: center; height :40%">
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKy3U/).

When i am putting any objects using javascript it somehow adjusts its height. Here is what i have done [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffGq2/)

How can i fix the height of the div

Comment: Use position:absolute; in css & see the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a `height` of `parent div`, unless a `height` with `percentage` is not working,
so you have to maintain a `parent's height`. check this http://jsfiddle.net/ffGq2/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use the position absolute :

```
#imgContainer { width:100%;text-align: center; height :40% ; position: absolute;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LKy3U/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Add position:absolute; css property fixed

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use percentages in height you have to use `position:absolute` to the `<div>`

If you don't want to use position absolute then rather use fixed height only.

For making it responsive you only need to adjust the width not height, so I suggest use `min-height:40%; position:absolute`